# Android - ImageButton Values / SharedPreference

Tags: android, database, android-layout, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

If you have time , please can you take some time for me ? I really need some help.

Let me explain;
Im working on an android app.

There is a layout and it has 5 ImageButton and a webview. When the users click on a imagebutton, without problem it calls a website below..but more or less i have 20 web site.i want to add an option for users..for example the user will choose a web site from Prefs. screen then automatically one of imagebuttons values (i mean icon AND its loadurl function) will change.

I created Pref Screen and i can see my website in this which i wrote in array.xml

but totally im not able to set them to Imagebuttons..

im beggin u.its our last curve..then it ll finish.

Im tried to use this code :

```
Data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = data.edit();
        e.putString("website", websiteVariable);
        e.commit();
```

but i couldnt.
Please explain me step by step clearly.
also i dont want that only for me,on internet there is no source for this issue.im searching and trying everything what i can think more than 6 days but nothing.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SharedPreference   Data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
   SharedPreferences.Editor e = data.edit();
    e.putString("website", websiteVariable);
    e.commit();
```

Basically what this does is allows you to store user information such as scores for a game, stats, and other variables.

The first line gets reference or creates the file to write the data to.

The second line allows you to edit the file to write new information to it..

```
e.putString()
```

Takes two parameters the first one being the Key to pull the value you out later, and the second being the value you want to put into the file.

The last line commits the data so that it is saved to the file.

You can get more info from the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Also if you want to pull the data out just do

```
SharedPreference   Data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
String value = Data.getString("website"); // use the key here to pull the data out
```

EDIT:

So for example if the user selects a certain image you could use a key to refer to each image and get the value later to decided which icon the user picked before.